# Cloud Vision API - Space as a number separator

Tags: google-cloud-vision

What to do to prevent text detection from dividing digits with a space into two frames?
For example: "1 200.00" is divided into "1" and "200.00".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you want to set custom separator to the text_detection mode, it's not possible as far as I know.

Even if it was possible all the words separated by space would be read as one word?

You can parse the json response and manipulate it as you wish.

> [Here is the structure of the response](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/fulltext-annotations)